# Como faço para trocar de visível para invisível entre dois formulários

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="box">

      <form id="form1">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <div>
            <button id="btns">Signup</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </div>
      </form>

      <form id="form2">
        <h1>Signup</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
        <div>
            <button id="btnl">Back</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Signup"/>
        </div>
      </form>

    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.google...amily=Roboto');

html, body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    width:100%;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(#5b82c1,#74a6f7);
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#box{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    width: 30%;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:18px;
}

h1{
    color:#5b82c1;
    font-size:2em;
    ;
}

form{
    width:90%;
}

form input{
    border:none;
}

form input[type="text"],
form input[type="email"],
form input[type="password"]{
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-bottom:8%;
}

form input[type="submit"]{
    background-color:#5b82c1;
    width:95px;
    height:45px;
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:46%;
}

button{
    border:none;
    background-color:#5b82c1;
    width:95px;
    height:45px;
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#fff;
}

.hiddenclass{
    display:none;
}

.showclass{
    display:block;
}
```

o código que em javascript que tentei:

```
var form1, form2, btns, btnl;

window.onload = function () {
    form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
    form2 = document.getElementById("form2");
    btns = document.getElementById("btns");
    btnl = document.getElementById("btnl");

form2.className = "hiddenclass";

btns.addEventListener("click", function(){
    form1.className = "hiddenclass";
    form2.className = "shownclass";
});

btnl.addEventListener("click", function(){
    form1.className = "shownclass";
    form2.className = "hiddenclass";
});
};
```

Comment: Mas o que não esta funcionando nessa sua forma?

Comment: quando a pagina carrega o form2 esta como display:none, mas quando clico no button Signup o form1 deveria ficar invisivel e o form2 ficar visivel mas mostra rapidao o form2 e volta o form1 como se num tivesse feito diferença

Comment: Olha ali, postei uma resposta. Parece estar fazendo o que voce quer, talvez um outro elemento da sua pagina deve estar interferindo...